# how does the html property "dir" work, specifically when assigned "auto"?

Tags: html, angularjs

How does `<div dir=auto>bla bla שלום bla</div>` work?

By majority of words? First character?

I'm looking for a solution that looks at the majority of characters in a span in order to know its direction (an angularjs directive would also be good, but if this is already built in HTML I'd like to know).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When an element has its dir set to "auto", the direction of the
>   element is determined based on its first strong directionality
>   character, or default to the directionality of its parent element.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.dir

> Characters with the left-to-right, right-to-left, and right-to-left
>   Arabic types are called “strong directional”, or just “strong”
>   characters. Numbers are a special case; their reading direction is
>   always left to right, but they do not affect the reading direction of
>   neighboring characters. Even numbers that are displayed with
>   Arabic-Indic digits have a left-to-right character direction.

In the example you posted, it'll be `ltr`.

Comment: btw it's not arabic type, but hebrew

Comment: I didn't say your example is arabic type, I know it's hebrew. Being annoyingly meticulous, they are both semitic language, the same family, which for practical reasons are historically written right to left.. :)

Comment: not sure I understand - why make the distinction "right-to-left, and right-to-left Arabic types"?

Comment: interesting question, I just pasted that sentence from an IBM documentation website, no idea about that distinction. Apparently such distinction exists: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr9/#Bidirectional_Character_Types